# how to set auto update file in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

Hi guys can you help me with my problem to auto update of file when it is modified in sublime text 3? I tried installing package but I want another solution like editing the Preferences-> Settings-User. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] it and add more details. What exactly are you trying to do? What package did you install? What behavior are you seeing, and how would you like it to be different?

Comment: I want to resolve this by just by adding some code to Preferences.sublime-settings not necessarily adding a new package. I want a functionality that when I have edited a file in sublime from the server and suddenly closed the WinSCP ftp clien for Windows, the sublime must tell me that I had changes to that file and will prompt a message telling actions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP works by downloading the server file to a temp location, which is then edited in Sublime. WinSCP watches that temp file, and when any changes are made it re-uploads it to the server. Sublime cannot tell when you close WinSCP, so nothing you put in `Preferences.sublime-settings` or any other file will help you there. You can set up WinSCP to always use the same temp directory for each server you connect to, so if your connection quits you can reconnect and upload the changed file.

Alternatively, you may be interested in the [`SFTP`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin. Among other things, it can sync your remote directory to a local one, and when files are changed they are re-uploaded to the server. This cuts out the need for WinSCP entirely.